# How to define a duration elegantly in Java 7

Tags: java, android

To define a duration, sometimes we just write below

```
long thirtyMinutes = 30 * 60 * 1000; // In Miliseconds
```

As of Java 8 with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework, we could make it more elegant using

```
long thirtyMinutes = Duration.ofMinutes(30).toMillis();
```

But as I'm still in Java 7 (Android), I can't use java.time.Duration. So is there anyway I could have it define as elegant as Java 8, instead of just ruing the multiplication equation above?

Comment: Can you use [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a backported library-       java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

```
//convert 4 hours to milliseconds    
long ms = TimeUnit.Hours.toMillis(4);
```

Similar for minutes, days, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Back-port

Just drop a jar into your Android project.

Much of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) functionality is back-ported to:

- Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- Further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The old date-time classes really are bad, so bad that you should avoid them whenever possible. While a valiant first-attempt in the IT industry, the classes have proven to be poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. And, no, they lack any way to represent a span of time.

---

Tip: Use objects rather than mere primitives. Regarding your example of [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class, use the resulting object in your code. Do not convert to a `long` count of milliseconds unless absolutely necessary. Also, be aware of potential data loss as java.time objects have nanosecond resolution, so converting to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) means truncating any [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)/[nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Note that you can do math on date-time objects, adding and subtracting `Duration` objects for example.

Comment: What a weird reason to use back-ported libraries!

Comment: @AntonMalyshev What is so weird? If you mean adding a library for this one particular use-case is over-kill, perhaps so. But if the programmers are doing this one task, they are likely doing other date-time work as well. Furthermore, using objects in your code rather than mere primitives like an integer count of milliseconds makes your code more self-documenting, provides type-safety,  and ensures valid values.